# Why do I only get a blue background with TileMill and OpenStreetMap?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill

I use OpenStreetMap Carto in Tilemill in order to export mbtiles for a small town. I managed to setup everything according to the installation guide. However, when I open the OpenStreetMap Carto project in Tilemill I only get a blue background which is set by Map {background-color: @water-color;} in style.mss. Other than that there is no rendered map to be seen. I checked my database in QGIS and there it looks ok. Since I'm very new to this, I've no idea where to look for the problem. Any suggestions?

PS: I had a problem similar to this one: [Error with TileMill and OpenStreetMap Carto project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146623/error-with-tilemill-and-openstreetmap-carto-project), and was able to resolve it by the suggested solutions the result being that the errors didn't show up but I ended up with the map showing only its blue background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be caused by your style.mss

Do you have more than that what you described in your style.mss

Try using one of the example styles such as  https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/blob/master/examples/geography-class/style.mss

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It worked with another example style. This helped me figure out the original problem which is - I think - that my database is only defined for zoom levels above 7. At the same time project.mml was centered on 0, 0 so that I didn't zoom in on the rendered map (a small part of Germany far away from 0, 0).